# Showing tax-refunded items at Customs in Japan

Tags: customs-and-immigration, japan, tax-refunds

I'm on a vacation in Japan and have bought some items tax-free in different stores (Bic Camera, Isetan, some smaller shops).

1. Can I use the items while in Japan?
2. Do I need to show them after check-in together with the receipts on my passport (at Customs) or can I pack them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[By law, you are not supposed to remove consumables from the bag](http://tax-freeshop.jnto.go.jp/eng/shopping-guide.php) they're placed in until you depart Japan. This seems to be very rarely or never enforced, though.

> Purchased items must be kept in the specified bag until leaving the country.

[The departure customs counter](https://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g294232-i525-k7900345-Tax_Refund_for_Foreigners-Japan.html) at which you drop off the form in your passport is often not manned (and will have a drop box for the form in your passport), and when it has been manned, people have been told that it's OK to have the items to be exported in your checked luggage.