# What duties and taxes would I pay in Canada on a camera from Japan?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, japan, duty-free, japanese-visitors

I'm visiting Japan right now (I'm a Canadian resident) and am considering picking up a digital camera (second-hand, if that matters). The value of the camera would exceed the 800-dollar personal allowance that I see on the Canadian border website. I would also be using my foreign passport here to get a tax-free price.

Given this, what would I be paying at the border when I arrive at Canadian customs? Is there a duty? Or am I just paying provincial and HST taxes? Do those differ if I'm landing in BC, or since my final destination is in Alberta with lower taxes do those apply instead?

Comment: YMMV, but your odds of being stopped at Customs for bringing in a used digital camera (presumably not in original packaging etc) are pretty much zero, to the untrained eye a $3800 Canon EOS 1DX looks exactly like a $300 Canon EOS 1D.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a duty?

Yes, you can make an estimation of it on the [Canadian Government website](https://www.cbsa-asfc.gc.ca/travel-voyage/dte-acl/est-cal-eng.html)

> Do those differ if I'm landing in BC, or since my final destination is in Alberta with lower taxes do those apply instead?

Running the above form, the tax of where you actually live in Canada are what would be charged

Alberta having a 5% tax, and BC having a 12% tax, all above the 5% duty

Comment: Ah gotcha, that's very useful. Does my $800 allowance get removed from the cost of the item? I.e. if it cost 3800 would I put in 3000 to that form and be charged $307.5?

Comment: Also considering that says it's an estimate only, what might make the cost be higher or lower?

Comment: @IronWaffleMan 1. You must declare the price you paid for the item (*Enter the total amount you paid for the product*). 2. The custom officer has the power to decide what value an object has when they inspect it, they can price it at whatever (I doubt it, but they can).

Comment: Usually you cannot reduce the allowance: it is more like "all or nothing" (but also there may be restriction on what item). Note: but you can ev. have a refund of the Japanese taxes.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi When you say 'have a refund of the Japanese taxes' do you mean I have to pay those to someone, or I can get them refunded? I've been using tax-free stores and showing my passport which means I haven't been paying Japanese taxes as a tourist for large purchases such as this, so presumably I wouldn't get a refund.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan: it depends. Often you must give passport and you have to pay the tax, but you get also a form (and stamped) to get further stamped at airport to get the refund. I do not know exactly how it works in Japan, but often "tax free" means you get taxes back (ev. without some cut of refund agency). Or are you buying the camera at airport? So all such part is unnecessary

Comment: @IronWaffleMan: you should research the tax free process before buying. Some countries make VAT reimbursement intentionally cumbersome and require special paperwork or forms to be filled out by the merchant. Make sure you know what you need and discuss with the merchant before paying.

Comment: @IronWaffleMan In Japan the process is very simple: you show your passport, fill out some paperwork, and simply don't pay the tax.  No need to apply for refunds at the airport etc.  (You are supposed to show the goods to Customs, but in practice nobody cares: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66412/showing-tax-refunded-items-at-customs-in-japan)